# How do I correctly specify the WHERE clause in this SQL query written in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

```
$query = "INSERT INTO directory_level_one (child_categories)
    VALUES 
        ('$category_name')
    WHERE
        category = '$parent'";
```

currently, I get the following error when I add the WHERE part in the above sql query.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE category = 'Philosophy'' at line 4
```

Comment: You cant use WHERE during INSERT...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a where clause for an Insert statement. Are you trying to update existing database records instead? In that case, use the Update statement.

Comment: oops, ya your right, I forgot to change it to an UPDATE statement. thanks

Answer (score 3):

[`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statements don't *have* a WHERE clause.

Perhaps you want an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement instead?

```
UPDATE directory_level_one
SET child_categories = 'your_category_name'
WHERE category = 'your_parent'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't use a where clause with an insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

**where clause can not be used in INSERT statment**

please read this before preceding further http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is this:

```
$query = "UPDATE directory_level_one SET child_categories='$category_name' WHERE category = '$parent'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to change your `INSERT` to an `UPDATE`